# A singular value inequality

Tags: matrices, inequalities, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, tag-removed

Let $s_1,s_2: \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2} \mapsto \mathbb{R}_+$,
$s_{1}\left(\cdot\right)\ge s_{2}\left(\cdot\right)\ge 0$, be the
singular values of a $2\times2$ matrix. Is it true that
 $$\left|s_{1}\left(M+N\right)-s_{1}\left(N\right)\right|+\left|s_{2}\left(M+N\right)-s_{2}\left(N\right)\right|\leq s_{1}\left(M\right)+s_{2}\left(M\right)$$
for any two $2\times2$ real matrices $M$ and $N$?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Comment: The paper http://www.ams.org/notices/200102/fea-knutson.pdf is possibly relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more general result.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary $n \times n$ complex matrices. Then, we have the [weak-majorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization):

$$ |s(A) - s(B)|\quad \prec_w\quad s(A-B)$$

This result implies your alleged inequality as a special case.

The above result follows from a famous theorem of *Lidskii*, which states that for Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$,

$$ \lambda^\downarrow(A) - \lambda^\downarrow(B) \prec \lambda(A-B),$$
where $\lambda^\downarrow(A)$ lists eigenvalues of $A$ is decreasing order (notice that here the majorization is *strict*)

For more details, see for example, Exercise IV.3.1 in *Matrix Analysis* by R. Bhatia.

Alternatively, you can have a look (for the singular value majorization result) at Theorem 3.4.5 in *Topics in Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson.

Comment: Watch out, though, for the fact that Bhatia and Horn & Johnson use opposite conventions in the definiton of majorization.

Comment: @Mark: Really? Seems like Def. 3.2.8 in HJ is the same as condition (II.2) in Bhatia's book (considering only weak majorization).

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson.  It looks like they switched conventions between volumes.